# Creation of entangled electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement

If one obtains two entangled in polarization photons by parametric down conversion and one of them is accepted by and electron 1 and other by electron 2 - are this electrons now entangled in spin?

Comment: The problem with this experiment is that an electron is a spin 1/2 particle and a photon is a spin 1 particle. Therefore, when an electron starts in a spin down state it's spin can be flipped by a photon with a certain polarization. However, a photon with the opposite polarization cannot flip the spin in the other direction as there is no other direction. You might want to reformulate the question with a spin 1 particle, or use the orbital angular momentum of an electron instead of the spin.

Comment: I realize that polarization of photons can not be connected with spin of the electrons. I reformulate the question like: If one of the photons in an entangled pair is absorbed by an electron or atom than this elecfron must be entangled with tge other photon. In what degree of freedom is this entanglement?

Comment: Why not the orbital angular momentum as suggested by @Crimson ?